# passing variable from while loop when user press link (php)

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am searching for a way to pass variable (`$result[1]`) to a session variable  from while loop within a link. will be glad for some help

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($dataset,MYSQLI_NUM)){
echo "<tr>";
echo " <td >", "<a href='Rate_Supplier.php'>" . $result[1] ."    
</a>","</td>" ;
echo " <td  >" . $result[0] . "</td>" ;
echo " <td  >" . $result[2] . "</td>" ;
echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: `<a href='Rate_Supplier.php?foo=".$result[1]."'>`

Comment: you may want to pass the variable as a parameter of the query string. Use [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for retrieve the data.

Comment: hi simone what should i do in the php file that i want the variable transfer to?

Comment: i sucsseded tnx alot!